# Are there any high-fidelity open-source drones?

Tags: drone-frame, autopilot

Are there high-fidelity open-source drones out there? We're looking for some models-- aka *digital twins*-- to run through some simulation models, in order to analyze them for full system performance. We'd like to have the analyses cover the autopilot all the way up to how wind gusts affect flight stability or how the structure handles a. crash. We think drones which are widely known and well-documented would be ideal for this.

Something like the [NXP Drone Kit](https://www.nxp.com/design/designs/nxp-hovergames-drone-kit-including-rddrone-fmuk66-and-peripherals:KIT-HGDRONEK66) is going in the right direction, but there's no documentation for the  LJI X4 500 kit, which means the airframe is left uncharacterized.

[OpenUAV](https://openuav.eu/about.html) looks very promising, but AFAICT it's in its infancy.